# UNSAF method for UDP in rfc 4787

Tags: networking, nat, rfc, stun

I was going through rfc 4787 and the author mentions about UNSAF method .
What is UNSAF method ?

Comment: RFC 3424 : http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3424

Comment: The link is right there in the RFC, the first time it's mentioned, at least one more time, and in the references…

Answer (score 1):

As selbie says UNSAF is defined in [RFC 3424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3424) and means UNilateral Self-Address Fixing.

When a client is behind a NAT, it doesn't know his external address. According to this RFC:

```
As a result of the nature of Network Address Translation (NAT) 
Middleboxes, communicating endpoints that are separated by one or
more NATs do not know how to refer to themselves using addresses that
are valid in the addressing realms of their (current and future)
peers.  Various proposals have been made for "UNilateral Self-Address
Fixing (UNSAF)" processes.  These are processes whereby some
originating endpoint attempts to determine or fix the address (and
port) by which it is known to another endpoint - e.g. to be able to
use address data in the protocol exchange, or to advertise a public
address from which it will receive connections.
```